# Use Python regex to parse string of floats output by Java Arrays.deepToString

Tags: java, python, arrays, regex, string

I'm working with someone's Java code where a key data structure is a `m x n x p` array, `float[][][]`. I need to get it into Python; currently my approach is to save the array to a text file using Arrays.deepToString and then parse that text file from Python.

I am stuck on how to write a regular expression that will parse the txt.
What I *can* do is find all the floats with their associated exponents in scientific notation.
I use the following pattern to do so:

```
float_pat = r'\d\.\d*(?:E-\d+)?'
```

This works fine to capture floats in scientific notation as they are output by deepToString. Note the values are all positive because they are probabilities. I.e., I don't have any issues with how I'm capturing the numbers themselves.

What I *cannot* do but what I would like to do is have regex search for any number of floats enclosed in left and right brackets. I tried this:

```
list_of_floats_pat = r'\[(?:\d\.\d*(?:E-\d+)?), )+\]'
```

where I'm trying to find one or more case of the float format followed by a comma and a space enclosed by square brackets. But that returns `[]`. Not sure what I'm not understanding.

Here's an example 2x1x1 array:

```
[[[0.6453525160688715, 0.15620941152962334, 0.1874313118193626, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 0.01050721017750691, 9.991008092716556E-5], [0.5904776610141782, 0.18175460267577365, 9.991008092716556E-5, 0.22716827582448523, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5]]]
```

What I would want is for the regex to return two matches:

```
0.6453525160688715, 0.15620941152962334, 0.1874313118193626, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 0.01050721017750691, 9.991008092716556E-5
```

and

```
0.5904776610141782, 0.18175460267577365, 9.991008092716556E-5, 0.22716827582448523, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5
```

that I can then just parse as strings with strip and split.

I've figured out a workaround where I just find all the bracket indexes. But I'd like to know what I'm not understanding about regexs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data that you have is both valid python and valid json:

```
>>> s = '[[[0.6453525160688715, 0.15620941152962334, 0.1874313118193626, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 0.01050721017750691, 9.991008092716556E-5], [0.5904776610141782, 0.18175460267577365, 9.991008092716556E-5, 0.22716827582448523, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5, 9.991008092716556E-5]]]'
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[[[0.6453525160688715, 0.15620941152962334, 0.1874313118193626, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 0.01050721017750691, 9.991008092716556e-05], [0.5904776610141782, 0.18175460267577365, 9.991008092716556e-05, 0.22716827582448523, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05]]]
>>> json.loads(s)
[[[0.6453525160688715, 0.15620941152962334, 0.1874313118193626, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 0.01050721017750691, 9.991008092716556e-05], [0.5904776610141782, 0.18175460267577365, 9.991008092716556e-05, 0.22716827582448523, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05, 9.991008092716556e-05]]]
```

You'll be better off parsing with those libraries than trying to do so with regex.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I had a feeling the answer was 'don't use regex because there's something much less painful'. ty.

Answer (score 3):

```
\[(?:\d\.\d*(?:E-\d+)?)(?:, (?:\d\.\d*(?:E-\d+)?))*\]
```

You an try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/9GergE/1

The problem with your regex

```
\[(?:\d\.\d*(?:E-\d+)?), )+\]
```

was that at the end just before `\]` there is no `,` which it was expecting.

Comment: Got it, I needed another comma because the bracketed arrays are themselves separated by a comma. thank you, that helped me understand